# How do I return the method request body in response using AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I am trying to return the body sent in a POST method using mapping template using `$method.request.body` as from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#transforming-request-response-body):

But it is returning empty data. Why?

`$method.request.querystring` is working perfectly.

The mapping template:

```json
{
    "queryStrings":
        {
            "MessageGroupId": $method.request.querystring.MessageGroupId
        },
        {
            "MessageDeduplicationId": $method.request.querystring.MessageDeduplicationId
        }
    },
    "body": $method.request.body
}
```

Example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://fsgn7j23ob.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/sqs?MessageDeduplicationId=1&MessageGroupId=1' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "data": "mgr"
}'
```

Expected results:

```json
{
    "queryStrings": {
        "MessageGroupId": 1
    },
    {
        "MessageDeduplicationId": 1
    }
},
"body": {
        "data": "mgr"
    }
}
```

Current results:

```json
{
    "queryStrings": {
        "MessageGroupId": 1
    },
    {
        "MessageDeduplicationId": 1
    }
},
"body":
}
```

Comment: What content type have you set in the integration mapping?

Comment: For your mapping template, set `application/json` as the content-type - that should work

Comment: it is already `application/json` ;/

Comment: Hm - can you go [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4800344/ermiya-eskandary) and click on create room/start chat? I can then help you debug it

Comment: Oh, @ErmiyaEskandary! you are also in Manchester! Great coincidence! Me too! I jumped into the room, but I assume u were busy. I sent u a connect request on LinkedIn, I appreciate your help! Thank you so much!